# AWS Ubuntuサーバーの使い方がわからない。

Tags: python, bash

「独学プログラマー」の16章のBashですが、自分のPCのスペックがwin7のためamazon awsのubuntuサーバをセットアップしてやろうと思っているのですが、やり方を調べても全然理解できません。
なにか他に良い方法ありませんか？

Comment: 「AWSでのセットアップが分からない」のか「Ubuntuの使い方が分からない」のか「bashが使える環境を用意したい」のか、質問内容(目的)がはっきりしません。

Comment: 申し訳ございません。bashを使える環境を用意したいです。

Comment: @taiki_k さん、つまり「AWS Ubuntu サーバーを使いたい」というのは taiki_k さんが思いつかれた解決法の 1 つであり、実際には「Windows 7 上で bash が使いたい」というのが本質的なお悩みだったわけですね。もしそうでしたら、タイトルも「Windows 7 上で bash を使いたい」や「Windows 7 から bash 上の Python を使う方法はありますか？」などのようにしていただくと、別の回答もくるかもしれません。質問文下の「編集」から自由に変えられますので、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash の上で Python を動かしたいというだけなのであれば、[あとわいとさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/44493/19110)に書かれている方法の他に、[Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) に付いてくる Bash エミュレータの上で Python for Windows を動かすという方法もあります。それぞれを個別にインストールした後、PATH を適切に設定すれば使えます。

Answer (score 2):

bashを使うという目的であれば、MingwをいれるCygwinをいれる、
Virtualboxなどの仮想マシン上にlinuxをいれる。

cygdriveを理解できれば、cygwin
できないなら、vagrant + virtual box でcentもしくはubuntuいれる。
bashつかいたいだけなら、vagrant init/vagrant sshすればすぐにでも使える。
以下、ご参考まで。。

https://qiita.com/mikoski01/items/c3984901c22a7736d726

AWSのEC2だと接続までに証明書の設定とか面倒で、初心者にははまりポイントありそう。

Comment: win10 なら WSL がありますが、質問者さんの環境は win7 でした :-(